# Store date in class

Tags: java, class, date, constructor, getter-setter

I'm trying to build class project that include (`startDate_`) and (`endDate_`) as instance variables. the problem that i have store the date in int type. Is there better way to do it ? if so, how i can use them in the constructor and setter and getter ?. which library i should include in this class ?

```
public class Project {
private int pid_;
private String name_;
private int statDate_;
private int endDate_;

public Project(int pid, String name, int statDate, int endDate)
{
    pid_ = pid;
    name_ = name;
    statDate_ = statDate;
    endDate_ = endDate;
}
// getter 
public int getPid(){
    return this.pid_;
}
public int getName(){
    return this.name_;
}
public int getStatDate(){
    return this.statDate_;
}
public int getendDate(){
    return this.endDate_;
}
// setter
public void setPid(int Pid){
    this.pid_ = Pid;
}
public void setName(String Name){
    this.name_ = Name;
}
public void setStatDate(int StatDate){
    this.statDate_ = StatDate;
}
public void setEndDate(int EndDate){
    this.endDate_ = EndDate;
}
// methods
private void updateTask(String Name){
    if (Name != null)
        this.name_ = Name;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you are just storing it, then store it in whatever from you get it in the input. If you want date operations, joda-time is pretty nice - http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 1):

Your first option is the standard `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` (available since Java 1.0). You'll have that available by default, so you don't need any 3rd party libraries, but they're unfortunately poorly designed classes and not recommended (the classes don't really represent what they claim to, they're difficult to use, and counterintuitively suffer from threading issues in some circumstances).

Two other (better) options exist.

If you're on Java 8, then the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) of Java date/time classes are much better. See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) for more info.

Otherwise, check out the widely used and understood [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) sounds like a possible solution if you simply want a date with no time component.

Comment: `Calendar` is also an option

Comment: java.util.Date is not a date, though, but a time stamp.

Comment: im working in building android application. So, now i want to know how i can fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

for me , the best way to handle dates is in **milliseconds**.

this way , you store the exact date in a "**long**" vaiable and you can always convert it to whatever format you want (Date, Calendar and whatnot).

```
long statDate_ = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endDate_ = System.currentTimeMillis();
....
Date whatever = new Date(statDate_);
```

hope I was usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

Date is a simpler class and is mainly there for backward compatibility reasons. If you need to set particular dates or do date arithmetic, use a Calendar. Calendars also handle localization. The previous date manipulation functions of Date have since been deprecated.

**Both Date and Calendar are mutable, which tends to present issues when using either in an API.**